# How to trigger an action when an input gets focus?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to know how to trigger an action when an input gets focused..
right now I'm using this on my template: `{{view "clickinput" class="form-control" placeholder="search..." value=s action="focus"}}`
and this as the view:

```
export default Ember.TextField.extend({
  onEvent: 'focusIn',
  focusIn: function() {
    this.sendAction('focusIn', this, event);
  }
});
```

and this on my controller:

```
actions: {
  focus: function() {
    alert('f');
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work..
I get this error on chrome: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The focusIn action was triggered on the component <appkit@view:clickinput::ember438>, but the action name (function superWrapper() { var ret, sup = this.__nextSuper; this.__nextSuper = superFunc; ret = func.apply(this, arguments); this.__nextSuper = sup; return ret; }) was not a string.`

why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out to be simpler than I thought..
I just had to write `{{input class="form-control" placeholder="search..." value=s focus-in="focus"}}` in my template

Answer (score 0):

I used your answer as a starting point so thanks! Here's what worked for me:

**Ember stats:**

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember           : 1.7.1
DEBUG: Ember Data      : 1.0.0-beta.11
DEBUG: Handlebars      : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery          : 2.1.3
DEBUG: Model Fragments : 0.2.7
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

**My generic functions, I call functions.js**

```
Ember.TextField.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-stripe'],
  focusIn: function() {
    return this.sendAction('focus-in');
  }
});
```

**My controller**

```
  actions: {
    focusField: function() {
      debugger;
    }
  }
```

**My Handlebars template**

```
{{input focus-in="focusField" type="tel" maxlength="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="Card Number" value=input.number autocomplete="cc-number"}}
```