# Calling action in Ember Input Helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have this input field

```
   {{input {{action 'test2' on="keyDown" allowedKeys="any"}} }}
```

I am not able to this action. Is there a way to call an action when we have something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, It is not possible to do it like this. As you are trying to bind "keyDown" event. Can't you achieve the same functionality by observing text box value. I have given the sample code here.

**Template :**

```
{{input value=myValue}}
```

**Controller :**

```
myValueDidChange : function() {
    // Code here
}.observes('myValue')
```

Comment: How do you read the value of the input in the `myValueDidChange` function?

Comment: Marco - I think the design would be to have the input bound to another member of your controller.

Such as:

{{input value=myValue}} in your template, which binds an input to myValue in your controller.  Then, in the myValueDidChange function, you can just read the most recent value of myValue.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays you could just write:

```
{{input value=myValue action="test2" on="key-down"}}
```

See for more info: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions

Comment: Is that possible to pass arguments to the action?

Comment: @jgomo3: Not that I am aware of. But you could just get the value from the controller. E.g. this example: `this.controller.get('myValue')`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option ,if you are going to need this in multiple places, would be to create a component. At that point you can indeed catch the key press. For example if you want a numeric box, you could do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/numeric-input">
    {{input type='number' value=val classNames='text-align-right'}}
</script>
```

and then on the controller:

```
App.NumericInputComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
       keyPress: function(evt){
       ...code here....
    }
});
```

and finally you can call it using:

```
{{numeric-input val=productCount}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to register an action in your controller and call it from the input-helper by an event.

action in controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

//Attribute as a component for your template
search: '',

actions: {

    query: function() {
        console.log('ApplicationController > query')
        var query = this.get('search');
        console.log('> ' + query);
        //do something ...
        // this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });
    }
}
});
```

input-helper with a **key-press event**:

Calls the action query form your ApplicationController on every keyPress Event

```
{{input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Query" value=search key-press="query"}}
```

here is a list of events: [Ember Events](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events)

Answer (score 0):

Credits go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122589/3890673):

```
{{input value=myValue focus-in="focus" key-down="keydown"}}
```

and

```
export default Controller.extend({

  // ...

  actions: {
    focus() {
      // ...
    },
    keydown() {
      // ...
    },
  }
```

and just any other event.

EDIT: Tested with Ember 3.1